# Parse Query, how to get parent's attribute within single call? (Swift iOS)

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfquery

I wonder if I can get the query parent attribute (not all but specific) within single query call in Parse.

Example:

**Class User**

```
objectId | username | email
------------------------------------
123abc   | Alex     | alex@email.com
123abd   | Ali      | ali@email.com
```

**Class FinanceRecord**

```
objectId | user (Pointer <_User>) | amount | type
-----------------------------------------------------
qwe123   | 123abc                 | 888.88 | Earnings
qwe123   | 123abd                 |  55.00 | Expenses
```

I am now on the app FinanceRecords page, and want to view all finance records of all users.
How do I query the call for class `FinanceRecord` along with it's user name at single call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `user` is a pointer you will have to call `includeKey` on the query object to retrieve all the properties contained within the related user object. Unless you do this for pointers, you will only retrieve the related objects object id.

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "FinanceRecord")
query.includeKey("user")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({(objects:[AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) in
   if(error == nil){
     // Do something with the retrieved records
   }
   else{
    // Error. Tell the user what went wrong.
   }
})
```

You can now iterate all the retrieved records, like so (within the error == nil condition):

```
if let financeRecords = record as? [PFObject] {
  for record in financeRecords {
    // Use record as a standard PFObject now. e.g.
    let value = record.objectForKey("value")
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah! Now I see, after you mentioned the key function `includeKey`. I searched again at documentation and indeed they have wrote for this case but I overlooked. Thanks :)

Comment: No problem! glad you figured it out